# script runs only after refresh! any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with images. When someone clicks at an image i want to open this page and shows the image clicked. But seems that the script runs only after refresh!

```
<body>
<img src="whatImg()" id="image"/>
```

// and here is the script

```
function whatImg(){
        var str = getUrlVars()["obj"];
        document.getElementById('image').src = str;}


function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m, key, value) {vars[key] = value;});
        return vars;
        }
            whatImg();

 </script> 
  </body>
```

Comment: I know the <script> is missing. Just cannot edit it right now.

Comment: `src="whatImg()"` isn't right. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeah...what *are* you trying to do?

Comment: it works but only after refresh. So the function whatImg() seems to be right

Comment: The `<script>` is executed, yes, yet not the `img src` attribute. Also, at which URL is that page located (since it's relevant for the code)?

Comment: I'm always amused by the people that argue with those trying to help them.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is change the `src` attribute from within your script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="blank.gif" id="image"/>

<script>
    function whatImg(){
        var str = getUrlVars()["obj"];
        document.getElementById('image').src = str;
    }
    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m, key, value) {vars[key] = value;});
        return vars;
    }
    whatImg();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited the code above to reflect what I have tested in IE9 and Chrome and it works in both. Make sure your code is placed near the closing `body` tag. If you're still having trouble, please revel what browser and OS you are testing on.